# recurrent declare in c

Tags: c, declaration, recurring

typedef void (callback)(int *p1, sStruct *p2);

```
typedef struct _sStruct
{
callback *funct;
}sStruct;
```

I have the following declaration, in C. How can I compile this recurrent declaration without receiving any error ?

For the moment I receive: **syntax error before '*' token** on first line.

Comment: What is "recurrent declare"? Do you mean circular declaration or self referencing?

Answer (score 11):

You can forward-declare the structure:

```
/* Tell the compiler that there will be a struct called _sStruct */
struct _sStruct;

/* Use the full name "struct _sStruct" instead of the typedef'ed name
   "sStruct", since the typedef hasn't occurred yet */
typedef void (callback)(int *p1, struct _sStruct *p2);

/* Now actually define and typedef the structure */
typedef struct _sStruct
{
  callback *funct;
} sStruct;
```

**Edit:** Updated to match the question's change of type names.

Also, I strongly suggest that you do not give the struct the identifier `_sStruct`. Global names beginning with a `_` are reserved names, and using them for your own identifiers could cause undefined behavior.

Comment: You can also forward declare the `typedef` in one go, something like `typedef struct sStruct sStruct;`. And don't hesitate to give the struct and the `typedef` the same name.